# Kitchen sink water pipes installed, not cloged but water does not drain at all

Tags: water, drain, pipe, kitchen-sink

I installed the new pipes after the old ones broke.
They are all installed as the old ones, but somehow the water doesn't drain at all.

See pictures:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]
(click to enlarge)

I believe that everything is as it should be, for example the wall pipe is bellow the sink (obviously)
The pipes are not clogged.
There is no leak spot, everything works.

But the water just doesn't drain!!

Once the pipes are full, the sink is filling up.
What helps? Once I free up the pipe from the right sink, from the bottom, and when I straighten it up, as in the last picture, the water from the pipe drains.

I have no idea what is wrong with it. Please help.

[image: pic5]

Comment: sounds like a blockage somewhere through the wall.

Comment: but why does the water drain if I pull up the pipe? shouldnt it be blocked as well?

Comment: Jasen, it was the wall, i got a pipe cleaner, and cleaned it up as much as i could, 4m in total, now it works as it should, i just hope that I just didnt move the problem even deeper....thx

Comment: I would recommend that you replace that flex pipe with smooth-walled, screw together fittings. The corrugations will collect gunk and lead to clogging much more quickly than smooth walled plumbing ever will and will be more difficult to clean out when they do clog. Your existing fittings are all screw on, so fitting new ones in will be simple since you simply rotate the "T" to point in the exact direction you need it. Also, a fixed trap will be much more functional as a trap than that flexible pipe which could be pushed out of shape, allowing sewer gas to pass the trap and enter your house.

Comment: I think the clog is due to the incorrect slope of the flexible hose. Replace it with PVC pipe instead.

Comment: Definitely need a trap not the Mickey Mouse flex pipes that screams DIY with no knowledge or ability to open a book.

Comment: Where in the world are you? That set up would not be allowed by code in the USA. What is different from the new to the old?

Comment: there's also a blockage in the vent pipe, that may still be blocked.